# System of equations, linear. Unique solution, infinite number of solutions, no solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

Suppose a set of linear equations are given:

$$2x + 2y + 2kz= 2,$$
$$4x - 4ky + 4z = 8,$$
$$3x - 15y + 15z = 0$$

For what values of $k$ does the system have a

- unique solution
- infinite number of solutions
- no solution

Comment: Did you carry through to calculate the solution in terms of $k$ with an augmented matrix? Once you get there you can look at the special $k$'s (sorry, bad pun) to answer the question.

Comment: where is the $z$ variable in the first line?

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: I tried reducing but I wasn't getting any appropriate solution. I believe the k variable will be in a quadratic form when properly reduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the solution in the bellow image.

[image]

Comment: While your answer is quiet good . I'd suggest you use MathJax to format your answer . [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a quick tutorial on how to use it . Thank you for sharing your answer . Hope to see more in the future.

Comment: Thanks! I can type latex code, but that answer requires many tricks for typing. Sorry about that!

Comment: This is correct. I think you mean 5 + or - root(96) not root(99)